# WP Plugin Easy fancybox embed form result on submit

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, fancybox, submit

I need to embed a form result on submit using Wordpress plugin "Easy FancyBox".

It is a little newsletter form. User just enters his email address and submit. Then it opens a fancybox with the complete newsletter form (form2) and the email address filled on step one.

I made it work but for the moment, when I submit, it embed form2 with email filled but without fancybox.

Here is my code for step1 newsletter form :

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="newsletterform.php">

<input type="text" name="email_address">

 <a href="#contact_form_pop" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit(); return false;" id="submit_link" class="fancybox">submit</a>

</form>
```

I also tried to put javascript out of the form, using this code :

```
$(function(){
  $('#submit_link').click(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit();
    return false;
});
});
```

It displays form2 in the fancybox but without the email address filled.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT :**

Here is my closest code. On submit, it displays the fancybox during 1 sec and then displays  form2 correctyl filled.

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="newsletterform.php">

<input type="text" name="email_address">

<a href="#contact_form_pop" id="submit_link" class="fancybox">submit</a>

</form>

<script language="JavaScript">

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

var form = document.getElementById("myForm");

document.getElementById("submit_link").addEventListener("click", function () {
  form.submit(); 
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: No, the solution given in your link doesn't seem to work. I'm using Easy Fancybox wp plugin and try to submit a form, not to embed photos.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved !

I put

```
target="form2"
```

in the form and create an iframe

```
<IFRAME src="newsletterform.php" name='form2' width="600" height="600"></IFRAME>
```

And now my form2 displays correctly in the fancybox.